# Communicate between React.js webview and native code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backbone.js, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm not talking about `react-native` here.

It's a hybrid app with native and javascript.
Javascript library we are using happens to be React.js.

We've used Backbone in similar setup and we had no trouble passing message between native and js world.

For native side to talk to js, we exposed a global variable (a Backbone View instance) in a page.

So we could do something like `window.login_view.do_login()`.

It was possible because we had the `login_view` instance.

However with react.js, I don't have an idea how I could create such an instance since my code looks something like the following, and there's no `instance` I can refer to.

```
 ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
     <Router>
       <Article/>
     </Router>
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('mainApp')
 )
```

How can a native side talk to react.js in a hybrid app?

Comment: If you have a globally available object or function in your javascript, surely your React components have access to it. `window.login_view.do_login()` looks like a globally accessible function.

Comment: Provider is a JS-Class so you can define a class property that you store to the window object as global variable using "react ref" (you can do this in componentdidMount i.e.)

Answer (score 0):

using the ref:

```
...
<Article ref={(article) => { this._article = article; }} />
...
```

in your article class:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    window.globaVarArticle = this._article;
} ...
```

now you can access the methods of your class Provider using window.globaVarArticle.[methodname]

Comment: Provider and Router are auxiliary classes. provider comes from redux, router from react-router.. My own class is the `Article`. How can I access the method of Article instance?

Comment: I updated the answer! it's the same as I wrote at first! just move the reference to your article class